# C#, start method if another method returns true

Tags: c#, boolean

i have the following code:

```
static void Start()
        {
            First();
            Second();
            ...
        }


    private bool First()
        {
           if()
                 {.....
                  return true;
                 }
          return false;
        }
```

there's probably an easy solution for this but i only want to start the `Second();` method if the `First();` method returns true

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `if (First()) { Second(); }`. Or is the problem that `First()` won't compile?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why not use an `if` stateent?

Comment: EJoshuaS, that's what i was thinking but i'm not sure how to include the true/false return from First() as the if condition so that Second() starts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static void Start()
    {
        if(First())
        {
         Second();
         }
        ...
    }


private bool First()
    {
       if()
             {.....
              return true;
             }
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean:

```
static void Start()
{
    if (First())
    {
        Second();
    }
}

private bool First()
{
   if (.....)
   {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```